# Arbitrage free pricing of option to trade stocks

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-calculus, geometric-brownian

Consider Black-Scholes model with constant interest rate r and stocks with prices $S_t^A$ and $S_t^B$ that satisfy the SDE's $dS_t^A = S_t^A(\mu^A dt + \sigma^A dB_t)$ and $dS_t^B = S_t^B(\mu^B dt + \sigma^B d\tilde{B}_t)$. I am owner of option A and want to trade with one stock A for one B at time T. What is the arbitrage free price of the option? How can I replicate the option?

Comment: Are you referring to a Margrabe Exchange Option https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margrabe%27s_formula ?

Comment: @noob2 yes, thanks for the tip.